# Getting Bitmap from Image using Glide in android

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, android-glide

I want to get the bitmap from an image using Glide. I am doing the following -

```
Bitmap chefBitmap = Glide.with(MyActivity.this)
.load(chef_image)
.asBitmap()
.into(100, 100)
.get();
```

It used to work with the previous Glide version.
But it does not work with this in gradle - `"compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0'"`

I want to use this dependency because this is the latest version.

Can anyone help me in this regard. Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you are using latest android studio you need to add   annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.0.0'
also

Answer (score 28):

```
Bitmap chefBitmap = Glide.with(MyActivity.this)
.asBitmap()
.load(chef_image)
.submit()
.get();
```

Answer (score 16):

There is little changes according to latest version of `Glide`. Now we need to use `submit()` to load image as  bitmap, if you do not call `submit()` than listener won't be called. In 4.0 Version, `submit()` added and in order to invoke listener.  One of user commented code is working with `GlideApp`. You can use below code to run with GlideApp if you are using.

here is working example i used today.

```
Glide.with(cxt)
  .asBitmap().load(imageUrl)
  .listener(new RequestListener<Bitmap>() {
      @Override
      public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object o, Target<Bitmap> target, boolean b) {
          Toast.makeText(cxt,getResources().getString(R.string.unexpected_error_occurred_try_again),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          return false;
      }

      @Override
      public boolean onResourceReady(Bitmap bitmap, Object o, Target<Bitmap> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean b) {
          zoomImage.setImage(ImageSource.bitmap(bitmap));
          return false;
      }
  }
).submit();
```

It is working and i m getting bitmap from listener.

Comment: thanks for checking with GlideApp, so i can included GlideApp also in my answer?

Comment: Yes, you can include GlideApp

Comment: Note! If use submit() then RequestListener callback will be called on background thread since v4.9.0.

Answer (score 8):

You need to set the size with RequestOptions in apply() and use a RequestListener to retrieve the bitmap. The mthod asBitmap() needs to be called before load(). So it will look like this:

```
Glide.with(getContext().getApplicationContext())
    .asBitmap()
    .load(chef_image)
    .apply(new RequestOptions().override(100, 100))
    .listener(new RequestListener<Bitmap>() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Bitmap> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, Object model, Target<Bitmap> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
            // resource is your loaded Bitmap
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add in your

```
dependencies{
  compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
  annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.0.0'
```

Also, give permission in your manifest.xml

Comment: compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'

Comment: There is not much changed since the last version of glide, you can implement this version also. if not working still let me know

Answer (score -2):

Try this in your build.gradle;

```
 compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
```

and load your bitmap like below;

```
  Glide.with(activity).load(m.getThumbnailUrl())
            .thumbnail(0.5f)
            .crossFade()
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .into(imageview);
```